# Disable print screen option in IE,but the code works fine with google chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Print screen option has been disabled in Google Chrome with the below js code.

```
document.onkeydown = keydown;
document.onkeyup = keyup;


function keydown(e) {
console.log("key down triggered");
var keystroke = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode).toLowerCase();


if (e.keyCode == 44 || e.keyCode == "44" || e.which == 44 || e.which == "44") {
e.cancelBubble = true;
e.preventDefault();
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
}

if (e.ctrlKey && (e.key == "P" || e.key == "C" || e.key == "A" || e.key == "p"||e.key == "c" || e.key == "a" || e.charCode == 16 || e.charCode == 112 ||e.keyCode == 80) || (e.keyCode == 44) || (e.keyCode == 123)) {
//alert("Inspect element & Print &cut/copy option is restricted");
e.cancelBubble = true;
e.preventDefault();
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
}

if (e.keyCode > 111 && e.keyCode < 124) {
//alert("Function option is restricted");
e.cancelBubble = true;
e.preventDefault();
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
}

if (e.key == "F11" || e.key == "f11") {
//alert("Function option is restricted");
e.cancelBubble = true;
e.preventDefault();
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
}
}
function keyup(e) {
debugger;
console.log("key up triggered");
if (e.keyCode == 44 || e.keyCode == "44" || e.which == 44 || e.which =="44") {
e.cancelBubble = true;
e.preventDefault();
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
}

if (e.keyCode > 111 && e.keyCode < 124) {
e.cancelBubble = true;
e.preventDefault();
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
}
if (e.key == "F11" || e.key == "f11") {
//alert("Function option is restricted");
e.cancelBubble = true;
e.preventDefault();
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
}
```

The above code works fine in Google Chrome.key code 44 for Print screen option is used.In IE all the function keys have been restricted,but the keyup and keydown function is not getting triggered,when in IE browser alone.

What is the alternate way to handle print screen option in IE Browser using jquery.?

And additionally the above code fails to prevent print screen when the user opens a bootbox alert pop up inside a web application.

Suggest a solution for the above 2 scenarios.

Comment: Just as a side note, there is no way you can avoid any lambda user to print what it appears on his screen, fortunately!

Comment: You realize this is pointless, right? :-) I can just focus the address bar (or anything else on my screen that doesn't obscure my browser window), and then hit PrintScreen.

Comment: In my case, Print Screen is hotkeyed to Lightshot anyway, which your code wouldn't have a hope of interrupting.

Answer (score 4):

**Don't.**

No matter how clever your code, you can't stop me from focussing a different window on my second monitor and hitting Print Screen there to get a copy of whatever's on-screen that you're trying to stop me from screenshotting.

Or I could just open the browser console (even if you block <kbd>F12</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>, I can still get there via the browser's menus) and type `document.onkeydown = document.onkeyup = null;` and break your entire guard.

It's not often that I "answer" a question by completely shutting it down, but you are wasting your time.